# File allows me to connect database but can't connect from another file (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm testing my project using XAMPP, CORS plugin on Chrome and accessing database with PHP files.

I have two files so far, a file to register user, that allows me to connect database to finish the registration, here's the file (i'm using testing data to know if connection and query are working and it does)

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "taxi";
$bd = "ruta";

session_start(); 

$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass,$bd) 
or die("Ha sucedido un error inesperado en la conexion de la base de datos");

$sql="INSERT INTO `usuario` (Nombre, Password, Cedula, Estado, Municipio,  
Email, Telefono, Tarjeta_Credito) VALUES('name', 'password', '12345', 'test', 'test', 'test@mail.com', '12345', '99999999')";

if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die();

 $close = mysqli_close($conexion) 
 or die("Ha sucedido un error inesperado en la desconexion de la base de datos");
?>
```

I have a second php file in the same folder at XAMPP's where my first file is, but when i try this query

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "taxi";
$bd = "ruta";

session_start(); 

$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass,$bd) 
or die("Ha sucedido un error inesperado en la conexion de la base de datos");

$sql="SELECT * FROM  usuario";

$close = mysqli_close($conexion) 
or die("Ha sucedido un error inesperado en la desconexion de la base de datos");
    ?>
```

it throws me this error

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Conexion.php on line 14
>   Ha sucedido un error inesperado en la conexion de la base de datos

line 14 is this one

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass,$bd) 
or die("Ha sucedido un error inesperado en la conexion de la base de datos");
```

Why is this happening? why i can access with first file but i can't with the second file?

This is kinda confusing to me.

Thank you for you time and attention.

Update:

First query response (using random test data):

[image]

Comment: Invalid credentials. Make sure you are using the correct values.

Comment: As i told above, it allows me to connect using firsts credentials but i can't on the second file using the same credentials of that database, so confusing.

Comment: Copy the entire content from file1 to file2 and check if the error continues. If no, you are probably with some typo in your code.

Comment: Nothing, same error, it's weird, i worked with php for a couple of months and it's the first time that i got this error.

Comment: It is impossible that the 2 files you have shown us, operating in the same context (i.e. PHP configuration / server) would exhibit the behaviour you describe. Even on MSWindows.

Comment: Man i'm not lying, i'm just telling you what system says, i updated the question showing the responses from php files

Comment: I found the solution, pretty weird, i think is some kind of bug but i solved, thank you for your help :)

Comment: Maybe some special chars and different encoding in your files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but i changed the password, yeah, the password that worked on my first php file and now it works with both files, considering that i'm accessing to the same table on the same database with same credentials.

Some kind of bug or something?

Comment: No, same password on same files, one worked other don't, then changed the password and both worked.

Comment: Sure man, no problem, thanks to all of you for your comments :)